# Automatically install a custom font in javafx

Tags: java, javafx, fonts

I have developed a javafx application, in which I want to make use of a custom font. I will use the font just once in the following button:

```
gui.SanswerButton1.setStyle("-fx-font: 80 Symbola;-fx-base: #17499F;");
```

What I want is to add this custom font automatically in every machine that runs my javafx application. How is this possible to happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You better ship the font with your application jar and then you have 2 options:

- if you use CSS use `@font-face { font-family: Symbola; src: url('Symbola.ttf'); }`
- if you don't use CSS load the font at application startup with `Font.loadFont`